# Running Apache Toree in YARN Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

According to this JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOREE-369), Apache Toree supports running kernel in YARN CLuster mode. 
But I am not able to run it. Below is the kernel.json I am using,

```
{
  "language": "scala",
  "display_name": "Remote - Scala",
  "env": {
    "__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__": "--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster",
    "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/hdp/latest/spark",
    "__TOREE_OPTS__": "",
    "DEFAULT_INTERPRETER": "Scala",
    "PYTHON_EXEC": "python"
  },
  "argv": [
    "/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/bin/run.sh",
    "--profile",
    "{connection_file}"
  ]
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Which version of toree are you trying to use?  That issue is solved after the release of `toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz` -- so my interpretation is that it is probably not yet officially supported. Indeed the whole Spark Yarn support is immature, if ever officially supported.